# Locus of z fulfilling an equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I am given this equation, and asked to find the locus of points for z in the Argand diagram:

$$\arg(z^2+1)= \frac{\pi}{2}$$

However, I cannot make any sense out of it, since I think $z^2$ is real and positive, so adding 1 by $z^2$ is still real and positive.  How can the argument be $90^o$?

Comment: $z^2$ is not real in general, since $z$ is complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\arg(z^2+1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\implies Re(z^2+1)=0\cap Im(z^2+1)>0$

Writing $z=x+iy$, we have $x^2-y^2+1=0$ and $2xy>0$

So the locus is the two parts of the hyperbola $y^2-x^2=1$ which lie inside the first and third quadrants.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Write your complex number $z$ as $z=x+yi$.

We now substitute into your equation:

$$\arg((x+yi)^2+1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\arg(x^2-y^2+1+2xyi)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Let $z_2=x^2-y^2+1+2xyi$.

Using the definition of the argument when $Re(z_2)>0$:

$$\arg(a+bi)=\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right), a>0$$

For our case, $a=x^2-y^2+1$ and $b=2xy$.

Hence, we have:
$$\arctan{\left(\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2+1}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

It follows that:

$$\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2+1}=\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$

$$\frac{x^2-y^2+1}{2xy}=\frac{1}{\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}}$$

Since $\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} \rightarrow \pm \infty$, it follows that $\frac{1}{\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}} \rightarrow 0$

Hence,

$$\frac{x^2-y^2+1}{2xy} \rightarrow 0$$

And hence it is only required to solve

$$x^2-y^2+1=0$$

This gives the solution $$y=\pm \sqrt{x^2+1}$$

Use the definition of the argument when $Re(z_2)<0$:

$$\arg(a+bi)=\begin{cases}
\arctan(\frac b a) + \pi &\text{if } a < 0 \text{ and } b \ge 0, \\
\arctan(\frac b a) - \pi &\text{if } a < 0 \text{ and } b < 0, \\
\end{cases}$$

Hence you should find that when $x>0$, you get the locus $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and when $x<0$, you get the locus $-\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

Note that when $x=0$, if we substitute into $\arg(x^2-y^2+1+2xyi)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we deduce that $\arg(1-y^2)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, and thus, since when $a=0$ and $b>0$, $\arg(a+bi)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, it follows that:
$$1-y^2>0$$
$$|y|<1$$

Thus your locus is as follows:

$$y=\begin{cases} \sqrt{x^2+1}, x > 0 \\ -\sqrt{x^2+1}, x < 0 \end{cases}$$

$$x=0, -1<y<1$$

Answer (score 0):

Following is the outline of a more geometric argument, though somewhat less direct.

The premise $\arg(z^2+1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Re}(z^2+1)=0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z^2+1)>0\,$. The first condition gives $0 = 2\,\operatorname{Re}(z^2+1)=(z^2+1)+(\bar z^2+1)=z^2+\bar z^2+2\,$. Therefore:

$$
z^2+\bar z^2+2 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

The above implies:

$$
|z|^2=|z^2|=|-(\bar z^2+2)|=|\bar z^2+2|=|\overline{\bar z^2+2}|=|z^2+2| \tag{2}
$$

But:

- $|z^2+2|=|(z+i \sqrt{2})(z-i \sqrt{2})|=|z+i \sqrt{2}|\,|z-i \sqrt{2}|$
- $|z|^2 = \frac{1}{2}\,\left(|z+i\sqrt{2}|^2 + |z-i\sqrt{2}|^2\right)-\frac{1}{4}\,\left|2\, i\sqrt{2}\right|^2 = \frac{1}{2}\,\left(|z+i\sqrt{2}|^2 + |z-i\sqrt{2}|^2\right)-2$
  from the [median length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)#Formulas_involving_the_medians.27_lengths) for the triangle with vertices $z, i\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$.

Substituting back into $(2)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\,\left(|z+i\sqrt{2}|^2 + |z-i\sqrt{2}|^2\right)-2 & \;\;=\;\; |z+i \sqrt{2}|\,|z-i \sqrt{2}| \\
\left(\,|z+i\sqrt{2}| - |z-i\sqrt{2}|\,\right)^2 & \;\;=\;\; 4 \\
\big|\,|z+i\sqrt{2}| - |z-i\sqrt{2}|\,\big| & \;\;=\;\; 2
\end{align}
$$

The latter narrows down the locus of $z$ as being a subset of points with a constant difference between distances to fixed points $\pm i\sqrt{2}\,$, which is a hyperbola with foci at $\pm i\sqrt{2}\,$.

Further enforcing the second condition $\operatorname{Im}(z^2+1)>0\,$ cuts off the $2^{nd}$ and $4^{th}$ quadrants parts of the hyperbola and gives the final answer. Depending on the formal definition of $\operatorname{arg}$ in the context, the endpoints $z=\pm i$ may or may not be included in the solution set.